# Naming Unit Tests that just calls a constructor?

Tags: unit-testing, naming

I'm trying to follow [Roy Osherove's UnitTests naming convention](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2005/04/03/TestNamingStandards.aspx), with the naming template:  [MethodName_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior].

Following this pattern. How would you name a test calling a constructor?

```
[Test]
public void ????()
{
    var product = new Product();
    Assert.That(product, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Constructor_WithoutArguments_Succeeds`

Answer (score 8):

I don't know how you would call this unit test but I strongly suggest you avoid writing it as there's nothing on earth to make the assert fail. If the constructor succeeds the CLR guarantees you a fresh instance which won't be null.

Now if the constructor of your object throws an exception under some circumstances you could name it like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void Product_Constructor_ShouldThrowIfNullArgumentSupplied()
{
    new Product(null);
}
```

So two possible cases for the code you are testing:

1. You get an instance
2. You get an exception

No need to test the first.

Comment: Fair... see your point, but you didn't answer the question. Your name does not match the naming template (Product is not a method). So if I leave this out you name it Constructor_????_ShouldThrowIfNullArgumentSupplied. 

The question if valid if you do test first, then you need to start somewhere. And I often have a classes with no behavior, that could possible fail. Eg. :
class Product()
{ 
string Name {get; set;}
}

Comment: Well then you see that there's a weakness in this naming convention :-)

Comment: :-) And that's the reason I ask the question. If you follow this naming convention then how do you name such tests. Right now I think you are right... don't write any test and allow entity which can not possible fail. I'm not a big fan of tests, and I'm trying to learn how to do "test first". So how would you write a test for a dum entity like I have.

Comment: Well maybe there's some other logic in this `Product` class that might be worth testing, like methods, but quite honestly writing a test for an empty constructor is pointless.

Comment: I do think that a new instance does call a method. I would warn you that following guidelines like this to the bitter end will be your ruin. So be forewarned, it is a guideline. A guideline is a way to keep you on the path. Paying attention to minutiae is not following the path.